# What does a double forward slash mean in a url aside from the protocol seperator at the begining?

Tags: html, wordpress, http, https

I have seen a lot  of urls lately that seem to have hijacked a portion of the site - 'www.example.com' In the example url: "http://www.example.com//wp-includes/js/apparently_user_defined_dir/from_here_on/index.html"  'wp-includes' is wordpress,  and js javascript - what has been done (typically) to these sites and what is to be done? (aside from notifying example.com or their host..)

Thank you.

Comment: I've found that it usually is an error in the code that generates the URL.  Most often a variable was used that had no value.  The server will navigate properly as if it was only a single slash.

Comment: The title does not seem to be connected with the text of the question (no “//” in the sample URL except as protocol separator), and it is unclear what is the potential problem with the hypothetical URL.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the domain the other are "path"
The link you entered is translated by browser to a HTTP request with the header (example):

```
GET //wp-includes/js/apparently_user_defined_dir/from_here_on/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2024.2 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: el-GR,el;q=0.8
```

Check this line:

```
GET //wp-includes/js/apparently_user_defined_dir/from_here_on/index.html HTTP/1.1
```

Its the server's job to reply to the request, so if the server knows that
`//wp-includes/js/apparently_user_defined_dir/from_here_on/index.html`
means its ok.

Most times this is translated to a path on a folder, but probably not in this case.

The page you entered returns a `Status Code: 404 Not Found` so ... your requested page was not found and it responds you with this error page ... which for some reason reports to the user no error. (We all know this is an example page.)